# url Rewrite two urls in a folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite Two URLs in a folder

first is

[www.example.com/mybooks/list.php?id=novel-15](http://www.example.com/mybooks/list.php?id=novel-15) to [www.example.com/mybooks/novel-15](http://www.example.com/mybooks/novel-15) for this i have the following code in mybooks/.htaccess file [.htaccess is in mybooks folder]

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mybooks/ 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /list\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ list.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Its working fine...

Now I want to rewrite

mybooks/search.php?search_word=mystery&search_option=all&page=4 to mybooks/mystery/all/4

i want to do this with out distrub the first rewrite option how can i do this

Comment: Why do you want to have 2 seperate things have very similar urls? Why not rewrite it to, say, `/mybooks/search/mystery-all-4`. While it is possible to distinguish between both urls you list, since the latter one has two `-`'s, it doesn't seem a smart move to me. By adding `/search/` to the url, you make it easier on yourself and it makes it easier to figure out what the url is for.

Comment: i cant understand wht ur saying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mybooks/ 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search\.php\?search_word=([^\s&]+)&search_option=([^\s&]+)&page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /list\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\d+)/?$ search.php?search_word=$1&search_option=$2&page=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ list.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: css/js isn't working due to your relative links.  You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/mybooks/" />`